# springboot 2.3.0 while connecting to h2 database

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, h2

In Springboot 2.3.0.RELEASE
I am getting the the following error while connecting to h2 database in the console

> Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote
>   database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200]
>   90149/90149

Comment: Can you show us the full string starting with jdbc: ? You seem to do it right but maybe a typo ? It should be: jdbc:h2:mem:test_mem , and the fact it tells you it's a remote db is suspicious.

Comment: H2 Console from third-party projects doesn't allow database creation any more due to security reasons and shows such error message, there is nothing suspicious. But specified JDBC URL should point to existing database created by application.

Answer (score 72):

You can fix this by setting the `spring.datasource.url` property like so:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Prior to Spring Boot 2.3.0-RELEASE this was the default, but I'm not sure where it's set. As of 2.3.0-RELEASE, the schema looks to be a randomly generated GUID.

Comment: Thank you very much  Chacewells. Its working fine with your guidance.

Answer (score 49):

Actually, your h2 databse is looking for a file called test.mv.db. But
that file was not present in your user directory. So, that it just
slapping you and asking you to pre-create it in that path.

**Note:** That is the root file where our H2 DB store all our information.

1. Add below line in your `application.properties` file
   `spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`
2. Go to your user directory, in my case, it is (C:\Users\subra)
3. Create a new file called `test.mv.db` and saved it under all file option like below.
   [image: Save Format]
4. Now restart your app.
5. Done

**Reference Screenshot:**

#### My Problem:

[image: My Problem]

---

#### The Result

[image: The Result]

Comment: > So, that it just slapping you and asking you to pre-create it in that path. 


It's asking him to create the database mem:testdb, not a file test.mv.db. Why?
I had the same issue and when I created this file, it worked!

Comment: Extremely clear and helpful!

Comment: thanks, this was exactly my issue. In Ubuntu, going to /home/<userName> directory and creating the file fixed the issue

Comment: Awesome.  The file is "testdb.mv.db"  if connect to  jdbc:h2:~testdb

Comment: Thank you. This saved my time. Perform the same if you are using the Mac too, and the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 36):

Step 1. In application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Step 2. Start your Spring Boot App and open:

```
http://localhost:8080/h2-console/
```

If you still face issue try pasting the URL value which you mentioned in application.properties `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` in

```
JDBC URL of h2-console
```

Then you wont face below mentioned issue
Database h2 not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149 (Help)

Comment: I don't understand , "try pasting the URL", can you provide an example?  JDBC URL of h2-console

Comment: @mattsmith5 op probably meant that paste the URL(jdbc:h2:mem:testdb) to the console's `JDBC URL` section.

Answer (score 26):

You are not able to connect to database because you are using old JDBC URL. Every time you start a spring project, JDBC URL changes as well.

Solution: Copy the JDBC URL from console every time you want to connect to a database or just use below property in application.properties file
**spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb**

[image: see screenshot]

Comment: Yes, this the main reason of my problem. And setting a name prevents this action repeating again and again

Answer (score 18):

Another reason for the error could be a the missing JDBC dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I got the exact same error and this was the issue in my case.

Comment: After adding this dependency I was able to see in app log the database url. Thanks!

Comment: yes, it works we also need jdbc to connect

Answer (score 6):

In Spring Boot 2.3.0 the property `spring.datasource.generate-unique-name` is set to true. This enables the random generation of the schema name.

By setting it to false the database is generated as in previous versions (`jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`). I find this way preferable, without the need to specify the URL manually.

Answer (score 6):

Create a file with a .mv.db extension in your project's folder. Make sure that the file's name ends with .mv.db otherwise H2 console does not recognize the file (I know it doesn't make sense and I have no explanation why :D). After creating the file, enter jdbc:h2:./devdb to h2 console's JDBC URL like this:

[image: Check this image out]

Then you should be OK!

Answer (score 3):

Step 1. Download h2 database engine from here:

https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Step 2. In application.properties:

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb

Step 3. Start your Spring Boot App and open:

http://localhost:8080/h2-console/

It must be working fine for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use h2 dependency with the old version (1.4.192).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.192</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I added "test.mv.db" file into "C:\Users\YourUserName" then restart the server and it's worked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: works perfictly fine !

Answer (score 2):

Since 2.3.0, default value of `generate-unique-name` is `true`.

You can revert to the previous behavior by following setting:

```
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
```

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62750194/4506703

Answer (score 2):

Even I came across the same set of errors when started learning data persistence with h2 database. The solution is in the console log itself. The database name is auto-generated by and can be found in the spring logs. The reason behind the error is after from 2.3.0 version release onwards if the URL is not mentioned its auto-generated.

Here is the log message which includes database URL:
****INFO 16096 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:f1dfeade-60dd-4809-8978-42547353b2f3'****

Answer (score 2):

Add property to `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
```

I had also missed adding the following dependencies to `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The missing part was we must beed to add JPA dependency

Answer (score 2):

**I had the same problem and I got it solved this way**

1. Go to application.properties
2. Add the following :

> ```
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
> spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
> spring.datasource.username=sa
> spring.datasource.password=password
> spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
> ```

now you can use **sa** for username and password for **password**

PS : that's usually the by default configuration that spring boot uses

Comment: This solution worked for me, but after set the password in the h2 console

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anybody. My issue was because I have this in my application.properties

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Not sure why I added this config before. But once this is taken out, it solves my issue

Answer (score 1):

Adding Spring-boot started JDBC solved my issue.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.5.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's error of H2-Database:

Solution -

Let's suppose `~/Test-H-2/Project-X/DB-files` path of your project (Database files)

1. create `myTest.mv.db` file in `~/Test-H-2/Project-X/DB-files` folder
2. Add `jdbc:h2:~/Test-H-2/Project-X/DB-files/myTest` to `JDBC URL` in H2-Database console

OR

simply you can create `~\test.mv.db` file & add `jdbc:h2:~/test` in to `JDBC URL` in H2-Database console

[image: Working for me]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **spring-boot-devtools** dependency from pom.xml and restart the application. for me, this worked.

Comment: Happened to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

copy the jdbc url --> jdbc:h2:mem:test like below. then your problem will be solved.

[h2-console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/780O1.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem while creating schema for h2 database in spring version 2.3.0 ...sometimes the database would connect but could not show me my structure of table so i tried chaneging the spring version and it worked like an magic try changeing spring version to 2.1.15.RELEASAE

Answer (score 0):

Replace the default *JDBC* url of *h2-console* from *application.properties* to use *JDBC Url*=`jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`
Below is the *application.properties*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in windows 10. Try to replace

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/testdb
```

with

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these two properties in `application.property` file

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

type url: `localhost:<portnumber>/h2-console` in browser
You will get a page regrading login database
Remove existing JDBC url in the page and put this `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`

Comment: This seems to be the same answer as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64005228/4214684

Answer (score 0):

I connect h2 by `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` but not `jdbc:h2:~/testdb`

Answer (score 0):

my solution for this problem is:

in case you you didn't made a database folder in home directory (in windows under the: *C:\Users**USERNAME**\test* || in Linux: under the: *~/test*) make it and add below lines to *application.properties*:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

it should help you to login.

((use blank username and password for H2))

Answer (score 0):

Adding to answers, which mention auto-generated database name in Spring Boot 2.3+ – this is the way how to get the generated name into H2 Console programatically in Spring Boot, so that you can keep the generated database name. It basically gets the first H2 database source and updates/generates the H2 Console configuration file ~/.h2.server.properties, which is then loaded by H2 Console when it is first accessed.

Configure *pom.xml* to use H2 types directly:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Enable H2 Console in *application.properties* (`true` is a default value):

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Code to use auto-generated database name:

```java
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.h2.engine.Constants;
import org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils;
import org.h2.util.SortedProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class H2ConsoleDatabaseAutoConfigurator {

  @Autowired
  public void configure(ObjectProvider<DataSource> dataSource) throws Exception
  {
    Properties properties = SortedProperties.loadProperties(Constants.SERVER_PROPERTIES_DIR + "/" + Constants.SERVER_PROPERTIES_NAME);

    List<String> urls = dataSource.orderedStream().map((available) -> {
      try (Connection connection = available.getConnection()) {
        if (connection.getMetaData().getURL().startsWith("jdbc:h2:mem:")) {
          return connection.getMetaData().getURL() + "|" + connection.getMetaData().getUserName();
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
      }
    }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (urls.size() > 0)
    {
      for (int i = 0;; i++)
      {
        String value = properties.getProperty(String.valueOf(i), null);
        if (value == null || value.startsWith("Local H2|")) {
          properties.setProperty(String.valueOf(i), "Local H2|org.h2.Driver|" + urls.get(0));
          break;
        }
      }

      OutputStream out = FileUtils.newOutputStream(
          Constants.SERVER_PROPERTIES_DIR + "/" + Constants.SERVER_PROPERTIES_NAME, false);
      properties.store(out, "H2 Server Properties");
      out.close();
    }
  }
}
```

The console will contain the current H2 name as *Local H2* menu entry:

[image: H2 Console]

The code is a composite of sources from H2 Console and Spring Boot H2 Console Autoconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE:->spring.datasource.url=**jdbc:h2:mem:nilesh**-->Should be same in console(**JDBC URL**)*

**application.properties**

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:nilesh
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding JPA Dependency to pom.xml fixed this error for me.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Here is my application.properties file, just for your reference.

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testapp
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring 2.7.3.
I had the same issue with mem:testdb not found. After trying out all the different solutions I could find in Stackoverflow, the only solution that worked for me was adding both "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb" AND "spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false" in my application properties file.

I thought that by adding just the "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb" should stop spring from generating unique name everytime I restart the application but apparently not. Manually creating the test.mv file did not work for me either. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everybody trying their own ways but solution to problem is NOT configuration but PHYSICAL.
See @Subramanian  answer.

Somehow , If you want to connect via console, Spring is unable to create a PHYSICAL file testdb.mv.db in root folder, i.e C:/USERS/testdb.mv.db.
I went to C:/Users/SHEKHAR , and created a New > text file ( don't save it untill you rename it to testdb.mv.db or .mv.db.
Restart Springboot, "Test Connection"  is Green and Connect , takes me to Console GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I am using spring boot 2.5. I tried many things mentioned above to solve the issue such as adding spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false and add "INIT=CREATE SCHEMA" in the spring.datasource.url to be something like
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:apiDB;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS user_scheme\;SET SCHEMA user_scheme;

But Nothing solved the issue

But when I added the below depedency to my pom.xml

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The issue was gone

I think the main reason is that in case of in-memory DB, spring needs a DB connection to execute creating the DB (apiDB), and this can not be done without spring data-jpa library otherwise it will complains that the DB does not exist.

Do not forget to add the below line to your application.properties

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: add the dependencies in pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Step 2:

add below code in the application.properties file:

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.username=sergey

spring.datasource.password=sergey

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

Step 3 :

run : http://localhost:8099/h2-console/

and entered the below details:

1. jdbc url : jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
2. user name : sergey
3. password : sergey

[image]

it worked for me .

Answer (score -2):

Please use this below solution it's working.

If you are dealing with the Spring Boot project, please change the JDBC URL **jdbc:h2:~/test** to **jdbc:h2:mem:testdb** in the login page, which is the default URL configured by Spring Boot.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67739929/2227743) (and mentioned in others).