# h2 localhost url different from testdb

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am using below spring boot config:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When my spring app comes up, I see the following:

```
H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:304a69fe-27f6-4271-a5c3-015f06910885'
```

However if i set the below in property file, i do see testdb being connected:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Can someone please let me know why do i need to explicitly set the url in property file? I had created another spring boot app recently with the exact same config but with spring boot version 2.2.4.RELEASE where h2 connected by default to testdb **without setting it in property file**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that with the latest versions of Spring Boot (2.3+), the H2 database name is randomly generated each time you restart the server. Similar post: [springboot 2.3.0 while connecting to h2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61865206/springboot-2-3-0-while-connecting-to-h2-database)

Comment: I am sorry but I think you didnt read my answer properly. I too mentioned the same. **If you are using any of this annotations - DataJdbcTest, DataJpaTest and JdbcTest in your test, then Spring through AutoConfigureTestDatabase will call TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, which in turn, by default, will configure an in-memory embedded database instance with an auto generated unique name.**

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty, I already knew the solution before posting this(add spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb in property file). However my question was why I would have to explicitly do it for one version of spring and not for another. As I mentioned, for the version 2.2.4.RELEASE, this wasn't necessary. As for the annotations you mentioned, I am not using any of those in either of the projects with the different spring versions.

Answer (score 0):

- [Reconsider default for spring.datasource.generate-unique-name as the current one makes test cases brittle #16747](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16747)

  - [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/9ff50f903f691bf0c016313c7ac8de6d04714f97)

> This change ensures that each test in a test suite that shares an
> application context gets a unique embedded database, to prevent
> inconsistent embedded database state between tests.

You can revert to the previous behavior by following setting:

```
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
```

Comment: This is not for any test suite, this is for the main application, connecting to h2 db

Comment: You can try changing this settings and see the [changes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/9ff50f903f691bf0c016313c7ac8de6d04714f97#diff-03dec1361411b5d52895337409916ba4).

Answer (score 0):

I have done all the things still it is giving me Database "C:/Users/abhis/test" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Update:

As you are using h2 console, you probably have a property called

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

If so then Spring's **H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration** class gets enabled and it does the auto-configuration as given below. (Check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.html) )

---

If you are using any of this annotations -  **@DataJdbcTest**, **@DataJpaTest** and **@JdbcTest** in your test, then Spring through **@AutoConfigureTestDatabase** will call `TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration`, which in turn, by default, will configure an in-memory embedded database instance with an auto generated unique name.

If you want to solve the problem for single test case, please use:

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
```

If you want this to apply for all test cases, then please have this property in application.yaml

```
spring:
  test:
    database:
      replace: none
```

Comment: I am not using any of the mentioned annotations, also this is not for any tests, I am connecting to h2 db from the main application

Comment: @user1318369 Do you have the property spring.h2.console.enabled defined? as i mentioned in my updated answer

Comment: yes, I do have that property set. As I mentioned, in both the spring boot applications I have that set(with the verisons 2.2.4.RELEASE and 2.3.1.RELEASE), however for the latter  I had to explicitly specifiy the spring.datasource.url, or else it assigns a random url which i can see in the application logs. So wondering why this different behavior?